# If n is such that every element $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is a root of $x^2-1$. Prove that $n$ divides 24.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a hard time formulating proofs.  For this problem, I  can see that if $n$ is equal to $8,$ this statement is true.  $(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ includes elements:  $1,3,5,7$, and all of these are roots of $1-x^2 \pmod 8.$  And obviously $8$ divides $24.$

But how do I prove this without depending on number calculations and only using theorems?  Help Please?  I need a step by step walk through of how to do this proof and what theorems would be appropriate to use.

Comment: Hint: First prove this for primes.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan What do you mean?

Comment: Is this what you are saying:

If, for each integer $k$
such that
$0 \le k < n$
and $k$ and $n$
are relatively prime,
$k$ divides $k^2-1$,
then $n$ divides $24$.

Comment: More extensive hint: Chinese remainder theorem + the fact that $(\mathbb Z/p^k\mathbb Z)^*$ is cyclic for any prime $p>2$.  Finally that it fails for 16 (to treat the case $p=2$).

Comment: See also [A high-powered explanation for $\exp U(n)=2\iff n\mid24$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/217006/242) $\ \ $

Comment: @user8268 In fact CRT can be avoided - see my one-line proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $n=2^\ell 3^{m}p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_r^{e_r}$. We know that $$(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times\simeq (\Bbb Z/2^\ell\Bbb Z)^\times\times (\Bbb Z/3^{m}\Bbb Z)^\times\times (\Bbb Z/p_1^{e_1}\Bbb Z)^\times\times \cdots \times (\Bbb Z/p_r^{e_r}\Bbb Z)^\times$$

Suppose $p>3$. We know $(\Bbb Z/p_r^{e_r}\Bbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic of order $\geqslant 4$, so $x^2=1$ for each $x$ is impossible. Thus we necessarily need $n=2^\ell 3^m$, that is $$(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times\simeq (\Bbb Z/2^\ell\Bbb Z)^\times\times (\Bbb Z/3^{m}\Bbb Z)^\times$$

Suppose $m>1$. Since $(\Bbb Z/3^{m}\Bbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic of order $\geqslant 6$ we cannot have $m>1$. Thus we have

$$(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times\simeq (\Bbb Z/2^\ell\Bbb Z)^\times\times (\Bbb Z/3^{m}\Bbb Z)^\times$$
with $m=0,1$. It remains to show $\ell=0,1,2,3$. Finally, if $\ell \geqslant 3$, $$(\Bbb Z/2^\ell\Bbb Z)^\times\simeq C_2\times C_{2^{\ell-2}}$$

If $\ell >3$ we have $2^{\ell-2}\geqslant 4$, incompatible with $x^2=1$. Thus you know that $n$ must be of the form $n=2^\ell 3^m$ with $\ell=0,1,2,3$ and $m=0,1$.

Answer (score 5):

**Case 1:** $5 \nmid n$.

Then $5^2 \equiv 1 \pmod n$ and hence $n|24$.

**Case 2:** $5 \mid n$. Let $n=5^am$ with $\gcd(5,m)=1$. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we can find some $k$ so that

$$\begin{cases} k \equiv 1 \pmod{m} \\
k \equiv 2 \pmod{5} \end{cases}$$

Then $\gcd(k,n)=1$ and hence

$$k^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$$
As $5\mid n$ we get that

$$k^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$$
But this contradicts $k \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$.

Comment: I cannot see why $(k,n)=1$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff  $(k,m)=1$ from the first relation and $5 \nmid k$ from the second relation. Thus, $(k,m)=1$ and $(k,5^a)=1 \Rightarrow (k, 5^am)=1$.... Or, if you prefer if $p$ is a prime dividing $k$, the first relation tells you it cannot divide $m$, while second tells you $p \neq 5$.

Comment: Yes, got it. This is a very elegant solution.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Ty :)

Comment: @Pedro We can use an old idea of Stieltjes to eliminate CRT - see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

$\,\overbrace{{\rm if}\,\ 5\!\nmid\! n\,\ {\rm then}\,\ n\,|\, \color{#90f}{24}\!=\! 5^2\!-\!1}^{\large \text{by hypothesis}},\,$ else $\,5\!\mid\! n =\!\! \overbrace{\color{#0a0}2^{\large j}\color{#c00}k}^{\large {\rm odd}\  \color{#c00}k}\!, \,$ &  $\,(\color{#0a0}2\!+\!5\color{#c00}k)^{\large 2}\!\not\equiv 1\bmod{5},\,$ so  $\not\equiv 1\bmod n.\, $ $\small\bf QED$

Comment: $\!\large \gcd(\color{#0a0}2^{\Large j}\color{#c00}k,\,\color{#0a0}2\!+\!5\color{#c00}k)=1\,$ isn't ad-hoc: it's [Stieltjes'](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647665/242) twist on Euclid's prime generation $\ $

Comment: See also [A high-powered explanation for $\,\exp U(n)=2\iff n\mid 24\,$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/217006/242) $\ \ $

Comment: Nice elementary proof. If you are looking for an actual residue class (a direct proof), fairly soon you are annoyingly stuck and wondering where to go when $n \ge 30$ and is a multiple of $10$. When $n = 70$ going back to $3^2 \!\not\equiv 1 \pmod{70}$ is of no help - where is the 'first candidate increasing' formula? And after much pondering you write out  $2 + 5k$ and hope for the best! (+1)

Comment: You can also use $2 + k$ since $5$ already divides $k$.

Comment: @Copy Of course, but I included a $5$ to make $\,x^2\not\equiv 1\pmod{\!5}\,$ as obvious as possible. The point of my first comment above is that by the linked idea of Stieltjes there is no need to "wonder where to go" to lift the unit nonroot $\,2\bmod 5\,$ upto $\!\bmod n\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

An algebraic approach is as follows:

Let us prove first the assertion for $n$ power of a prime. So suppose $\mathbb{Z/p^eZ}$ is such that for all $x\in(\mathbb{Z/p^eZ})^*$, $x^2-1=0$, then all the elements of the group $(\mathbb{Z/p^eZ})^*$ have order $2$, then by the [First Sylow Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems#Sylow_theorems) $(\mathbb{Z/p^eZ})^*$ has order $2^n$ for some $n$. Thus $\varphi(p^e)=p^{e-1}(p-1)=2^n$; [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#.CF.86.28pk.29_.3D_pk_.E2.88.92_pk_.E2.88.92_1_.3D_pk_.E2.88.92_1.28p_.E2.88.92_1.29).

Now I claim that we must have that $p=2,3$. For suppose not, then $[p^e-2]^2=[p^{2e}-4p^e+4]=[4],$ with $4<p$, however, as  $p^e-2$ must be invertible in $\mathbb{Z/p^e}$; $e=1$, this is a contradiction. So we can only have $p=2$ with $e=0,1,2,3$ or $p=3$ with $e=0,1$

Now, let $n$ be such that the property holds for $(\mathbb{Z/nZ})^*$. Let $n=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_n^{e_n}$ be its prime factorization,then $$(\mathbb{Z/nZ})^*\simeq((\mathbb{Z/p_1^{e_1}Z}))^*\times\cdots\times(\mathbb{Z/p_m^{e_m}Z})^*,$$

and so the property must also hold for $(\mathbb{Z/p_i^{e_i}Z})^*$, hence $m\leq 2$ with $p_1,p_2\in\{2,3\}$, $e_1=0,1,2,3$ and $e_2=0,1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x^2 = 1$ for every element of an abelian group, then it must have a very particular structure.

The answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/522360/14972) describe the structure of $(\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})^\times$.

Answer (score -1):

Let $x=2m+1$.

$x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)=(2m+2)(2m)=2^2m(m+1)$.

$m(m+1)$ is divisible by $6$ except when $m \equiv 1 $ or $4$$(mod 6)$, and $x^2-1$ is a multiple of $24$ except for those cases. Let's call the cases in which $m(m+1)$is divisible by 6 as Case I and others as Case II.

$2^2m(m+1)$ must be divisible by $n$ for arbitrary $m$. The periodicity of appearance of factors $2$ and $3$ in $m(m+1)$ needs to be discussed here since they are the factors which frequently appear in $m(m+1)$. If there's no such periodicity, not every odd elements will be divided by $n$.

Case I:

When $m=0$, $2^2m(m+1)\equiv 0(mod n)$.

When $m=2$, $2^2m(m+1)\equiv 24(mod n)$.

When $m=3$, $2^2m(m+1)\equiv 48(mod n)$.

When $m=5$, $2^2m(m+1)\equiv120(mod n)$.

Case II:

When $m=1$, $2^2m(m+1)\equiv8(mod n)$.

When $m=4$, $2^2m(m+1)\equiv80(mod n)$.

If for every element of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$, $x^2-1$ is divisible by $n$, then n must be a divisor of $8$ and divide $24$.

Comment: That is not correct. $(\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z)^\times$ also enters in the picture, say, since $1^2=5^2=7^2=11^2=1$.