# Prove that if b is coprime to 6 then $b^2 \equiv 1 $ (mod 24)

Tags: number-theory

Let $\gcd(b,6) = 1$. Prove that $b^2 \equiv 1 $ (mod 24).

Now I have that as $\gcd(b,6) = 1$, we know that  $3\nmid b $ and $2\nmid b$ (else the GCD would be 3 or 2 resp.)

So as $2\nmid b$, $b$ must be odd. Hence $b^2$ is also odd.

Then I'm not sure where to take it from here? Maybe I've gone down the wrong path to start with, and should be looking more along the lines of the Chinese Remainder Theorem? I'm not sure.

Comment: Since $b^2$ is a perfect square, we have that $b^2 = 1,4,9,16$ modulo $24$. All of these, besides $1$, require that $2 | b$ or $3 | b$.

Comment: Thank you! this is a very nice simple trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with $b$ is odd, so $b = 2k + 1$, and $b^2 - 1 = 4k^2 + 4k = 4k(k+1)$ clearly divisible by $8$. So we need to show that $b^2 - 1$ is divisible by$3$. Since $b$ is not divisible by $3$, $b = 3k + 1$ or $b = 3k +2$. If $b = 3k + 1$, then $b - 1 = 3k$ and $3 | b - 1$, so $3 | b^2 - 1$. And if $b = 3k + 2$, then $b + 1 = 3k + 3$ which is divisible by $3$. So $3 | (b +1 )(b - 1) = b^2 - 1$. So $3 | b^2 - 1$ and since $gcd(3,8) = 1$, $24 | b^2 - 1$.

Comment: Thank you! I had previously shown if b is odd then $b^2 \equiv 1$ (mod 8) so I feel as this is incorporated in to your anwser it bodes well!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\rm\ 3\nmid b,\,$ so $\rm\, mod\ 3\!:\ b\,\equiv\, \pm1\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ b^2\equiv 1$

$\rm\ \ and \ \  2\nmid b,\,$ so $\ \rm  mod\ 8\!:\, b\equiv \pm1,\pm3\,\Rightarrow b^2\equiv1,\ $ so $\rm\,\ 3,8\mid b^2\!-\!1 \Rightarrow\, 3\cdot 8\mid b^2\!-\!1$

**Remark** $\ $ More generally see the [Carmichael function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function)

Comment: By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3280360/242) $n=24$ is the largest $n$ such that every $b$ coprime to $n$ satisfies $b^2\equiv 1\pmod n.\ $ See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2350435/242).