# All natural number solutions of the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Can you find all natural number solutions of this equation?
I tried puting it in wolfram alpha and some other math problem solvers but they just solve it for one solution $$x = 2$$ and $$y = 1$$

$$y^{2} = \frac{24}{49}x + \frac{1}{49}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `linear-algebra`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just
$$49y^2=24x+1$$
$$y^2\equiv1\mod{24}$$
Trying the values of $y$ in the least residue system gives the solutions
$$y\equiv\{1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23\}\mod{24}$$
For which the integer value of $x$ is just given by
$$x=\frac{49y^2-1}{24}$$
So there are infinitely many natural number solutions of the form
$$y=\begin{cases}1+24k\\5+24k\\7+24k\\11+24k\\13+24k\\17+24k\\19+24k\\23+24k\end{cases}$$
$$x=\frac{49y^2-1}{24}$$
Where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k\ge0$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524789/if-n-is-such-that-every-element-mathbbz-n-mathbbz-is-a-root-of-x2/524849#524849

Answer (score 0):

$y^2=\frac{24}{49}x+\frac{1}{49}$

Multiply through by $49$: $49y^2=(7y)^2=24x+1$

Rearrange by moving $1$ to LHS: $(7y)^2-1=(7y+1)(7y-1)=24x\Rightarrow x=\frac{(7y+1)(7y-1)}{24}$

In order that $x$ be an integer, $(7y+1)(7y-1)$ must be even (to be divisible by the even number $24$), so $y$ must be odd, and since either $(7y+1)$ or $(7y-1)$ must be divisible by $3$ (since there is a factor of $3$ in $24$), $y$ cannot be divisible by $3$. So pick $y$ from $\{1,5,7,11,13,17,\dots \}$, plug it in to $x=\frac{(7y+1)(7y-1)}{24}$, and integer values for $x$ will pop out.

Comment: Do you think that all solutions for y are prime numbers?

Comment: @Adrian C No. If you continue the list of odd numbers not divisible by $3$, you get numbers including $25,35,49,55$ etc. which are not prime.

Comment: Do you think that $1$ is prime?

Comment: Not sure who the question is directed to, but see for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120/why-is-1-not-a-prime-number)