# If $\,k\mid n^2-1\,$ for all $n$ coprime to $k$ then $k\mid 24\ $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This comes from some university's admission test. Here's a translation of an excerpt of a problem:

A positive integer $k$ is a *cool* number if for every natural number $n$ coprime with $k$, the quantity $n^2 - 1$ is divisible by $k$.

The original problem asked for the biggest *cool* number below a certain threshold, but I was interested in finding all of them. I managed to prove that $k \in \lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24 \rbrace$ satisfies the contidion, but, to my surprise, I couldn't find more! Crunching some numbers on a computer revealed that these are the only *cool* numbers less than $10^9$. This  has led me to the following conjecture:

$$\lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24 \rbrace \mathrm{\ are \ the \ only \ } \mathit{cool} \mathrm{\ \, numbers.}$$

Beautiful, isn't it? I've attempted to prove this by way of contradiction. My idea was, assume there is a *cool* $k > 24$, get an upper bound $M$ on it, show one-by-one that no natural number $n$ s.t. $24 < n < M$ satisfies the condition, end the proof. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to attack this problem. I've noticed a neat little fact about the conjectured *cool* numbers, they're the divisors of 24, but this may be a coincidence and I don't see how I could use this fact.

Comment: I would day that the biggest cool number is $4$ (in Celsius degrees)

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h15033p106668

Comment: This has a [one line proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3280360/242)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claim: If $p$ divides $k$ with $p>3$ then $k$ is not cool.

Proof: Take $n$ coprime with $k$ such that $n$ is congruent to $2\bmod p$ (possible by the chinese remainder theorem) and notice $p\nmid n^2-1$.

Claim: If $9$ divides $k$ then $k$ is not cool.

Proof: Take $n$ coprime with $k$ such that $n$ is congruent to $2\bmod 9$ (possible by the chinese remainder theorem) and notice $9\nmid n^2-1$ so $k\nmid n^2-1$

Claim: If $16$ divides $k$ then $k$ is not cool.

Proof: Take $n$ coprime with $k$ such that $n$ is congruent to $3\bmod 16$ (possible by the chinese remainder theorem) and notice $16\nmid n^2-1$ so $k\nmid n^2-1$

Finally one can check that $2,4,8$ and $3$ work by inspection, so by the chinese remainder all of the following work,

$\{1,3,2,6,4,12,8,24\}$

Comment: CRT can be avoided - see this [one line proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3280360/242) using an old idea of Stieltjes. Please strive to search for dupes of FAQs before posting further dupe answers.