# For what values of $n$ are all the units (except 1) of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ order 2?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic, alternative-proof

The answer is: 2, 4, 8 and 3, 6, 12, 24. I can prove it, but I suspect there is a simpler proof.

First, notice that $|\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_{n}| = \varphi(n)$, and hence that $\varphi(n)$ must be a power of 2. If $p^2$ divides $n$ then $p$ divides $\varphi(n)$, so if $p > 3$ then $p$ divides $n$ at most once. Suppose $p |n$ exactly once. Then by the Chinese Remainder Theorem,

$$\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_{n} \cong \mathbb{Z}^{\times}_{n/p}\times \mathbb{Z}^{\times}_{p}$$

but $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_{p} \cong C_{p-1}$ has an element of order $p-1 > 2$. Therefore the only options are $3 \cdot 2^n$ and $2^n$. Manual checking shows $n=1,2,3$ works in the first case and $n=0, 1, 2, 3$ in the second case. Mod $2^k$ for $k \ge 4$ we have $3^2 = 9$, and mod $3 \cdot 2^k$ for $k \ge 4$ we have $5^2 = 25$.

That's short enough now, but I'm skipping a lot of details. The nearby exercises were all pretty easy, but this took me a while. Am I missing an easier way?

Comment: An equivalent formulation is: when is $\lambda(n)=2$?. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function

Comment: @lhf Of the top two proofs there, Pedro's is very close to mine (but a little simpler) and N.S.'s proof is probably what I'm looking for. Happy to close as duplicate!

Comment: Yes, the [this one line proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3280360/242) in the first linked dupe is much easier (and more elementary).