# The multiplicative subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}/(n)$, $H = \{x^p= 1 : x \in \Bbb{Z}/(n)\}$, prime $p$, has order $p^k$ for some $k$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, prime-numbers

Take the set of integers modulo $n$, written $\Bbb{Z}/(n)$ and any prime $p$ and consider the multiplicative subgroup specified by $H^{\times} = \{ x^p = 1: x \in \Bbb{Z}/(n)^{\times}\}$, then $|H^{\times}| = p^k$ for some $k$.  Is this already known?

Generalizing, from what I can tell looking at the results of some simple python code.  I think the conjecture could be:

Let $p \gt 0$ be any natural with prime factors $p_1, \dots, p_r$, then $|H^{\times}| = p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_r^{e_r} = $ some composition of powers of the prmes making up $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in fact, the structure of the group $\mathbb{Z}/(n)^\times$ is known completely (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) or the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/522360); in particular, Hurkyl's answer sketches an elegant proof using the $p$-adic logarithm).

In particular, from these descriptions one can easily deduce the following values for $k$.  Let $a_p(n)$ denote the number of distinct prime factors $q$ of $n$ such that $p\mid q-1$.  If $p$ is odd, $k=a_p(n)$ if $p^2\not\mid n$, and $k=a_p(n)+1$ if $p^2\mid n$.  If $p=2$, $k=a_2(n)$ if $4\not\mid n$, $k=a_2(n)+1$ if $4\mid n$ but $8\not\mid n$, and $k=a_2(n)+2$ if $8\mid n$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. There is a theorem saying that given G is a finite group, G is a p-group iff |G|=p^k for some k. The proof requires Lagrange Theorem and Cauchy's Theorem.

Comment: Oh, I thought the question was asking _what_ the value of $k$ is.  But I see that it could be read this way too...